# How to Call Object member function in JNI?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

I want to call a member function in JNI but it go crash,and I do not what happened

This is My Java Code

```
 public int SERIAL_hashCode() {
    String serial = Build.SERIAL;
    return serial.hashCode();
}
```

I want to realization this function in jni

This is My JNI Code

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL native_SERIAL_hashCode(JNIEnv * env, jclass obj) {
    jclass buildClass = (jclass)env->NewGlobalRef(env->FindClass("android/os/Build"));
    jfieldID serialId = env->GetStaticFieldID(buildClass,"SERIAL","Ljava/lang/String;");
    jobject serial = (jobject)env->GetStaticObjectField(buildClass,serialId);

    jclass stringClass = (jclass)env->FindClass("java/lang/String");
    jmethodID hashId = env->GetMethodID(stringClass,"hashCode","()I");

    jint hash = (jint)env->CallObjectMethod(serial,hashId);

    return hash;
}
```

But when it run ,it go crash,what's wrong with my jni code? 
Thanks!

Comment: Some error checking to determine which line is failing is probably in order?

Comment: Use debug  https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html#enable-debug

Comment: It Crash in The sentence env->CallObjectMethod(serial,hashId);

Comment: try adding your crash log

Comment: Firstly, the method name should EXACTLY match `jmethodID hashId = env->GetMethodID(stringClass,"SERIAL_hashCode","()I");` . Also, try using `CallIntMethod` instead of `CallObjectMethod`

Comment: Thanks to Ankur Aggarwal ,you are right